# c# How to call existing item of form having its name stored in new string?

Tags: c#, variables, object, datagridview

I have multiple datagrids and i would like to move data from one to another.
The problem is:

I have their names "made" into string variables:

```
string gridfrom = "datagrid" + cplist1.SelectedItem.ToString();
string gridto = "datagrid" + cplist2.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

In this case, i know that gridfrom = datagridMAR and gridto = datagridAPR
But gridfrom and gridto changes according to the listboxes selected items.

How do i call these objects (already existing in the form) to change its properties? For example:

```
gridto.DataSource = gridfrom;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you not set the datasource of gridfrom to gridto? use the same approach that you are using to load data into gridfrom to load data into gridto.

why are you having two datagrid's showing the same data?

Comment: One way is to store references to the Datagrids in a `Dictionary<string,DataGrid>`

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you an elegant way of dealing with this situation without getting into dynamic type loading, etc

Create a custom type, say

```
class GridName {
    public DataGridView Grid {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set;}

    public GridName(DatagridView grid, string name) {
        Grid = grid;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string override ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of adding a `string` into the cplist1 and cplist2, simply add `GridName` object into it. It will display the name correctly and also when you want the grid associated with it, you can access the `.Grid` property

There are many other ways of doing it. For example, you can use `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` property.

I would definitely resist against trying to convert the grid name into a DatagridView object.